# PHP curl hash_hmac

Tags: php, curl, hmacsha1

Need help on this .... I need to get json data from API call from a URL. It said the called needs..

1. Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. HTTP HEADERS : key ---> APIKEY
3. HTTP HEADERS : sig ---> HMAC-SHA1 signature of POST Data with SECRET KEY
4. POST PARAMETER: timestamp ----> Current Unix Timestamp

This is my code...

```
$key = 'APIKEY';
$secret = 'APISECRET';

$timestamp = time(); 
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $timestamp, $secret);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.domain.com/getticker");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "timestamp=".time());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","key: ".$key,"sig: ".$signature));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

It gave me the error message {"error":"Invalid Signature!"}.
Any clues?

Comment: {"error":"Invalid Signature!"}

Comment: You shpuld change `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "timestamp=".time());` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "timestamp=".$timestamp);` in order to post the same value you use in the signature.

Comment: In fact your signature is wrong, you define `$secret_key` but use `$secret` to hash. `$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $timestamp, $secret_key);`

Comment: i put the first question like nobody answer it. so i tried a second one. sorry abt that. just need a fix on this code urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$key = 'APIKEY';
$secret_key = 'APISECRET';

$timestamp = time(); 
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $timestamp, $secret);
```

should be

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $timestamp, $secret_key);
```

your $secret is not defined. unless you just didn't paste it that would cause the error

Comment: opps, my bad. actually in my code it is $secret. not $secret_key. must have mixed up somewhere.

Comment: oh okey, you might want to paste a bit more code

Comment: i edited the question again to reflect what i did in my code, the TOP one.

Comment: which api exactly are you using?

Comment: it is from fybsg.com.
the documentation is on http://docs.fyb.apiary.io/
the public API is not an issue. The Private one caused me headache. I would like to use the API function getaccinfo.

Comment: i tried looking up their api documentation but its terrible.